# Java Socket: Why client don't reply server

Tags: java, sockets, connection, client

I want to write a client-sever program in which server and client send messages to each other. First, my server send a message to client, then the client reply. Next, my server send another message, the client reply. The problem is, on my first message induced by the server, the client does not respond. 
My server:

```
public class Server {
public void go() {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
        System.out.println("Server listening ...");
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        try (
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            String input;
            printWriter.println(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
            while ((input = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(input);
                printWriter.println(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
                if(input == "Bye") break;
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.go();
}
```

}

My client:

```
public class Client {

public void go() {
    try {
        try (
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            String input;
            while ((input = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("1");
                System.out.println(input);
                printWriter.println(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
            }
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.go();
}
```

}

Are there some problems with my code?

Comment: Method `ServerSocket#accept()` 


    Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.

Answer (score 0):

Your client connects and then blocks reading a line from the server.

Your server accepts the connection and then blocks reading a line from the client.

I don't know what you were expecting to happen next, but it won't. Somebody needs to send something.

Comment: I'm newbie to server-client programming, what do you mean by "blocks reading a line", I just want my client reply the server and my server send messages to client

Comment: Reply to what? Everybody is receiving and nobody is sending anything to receive.

Comment: how can somebody send something to the other?

Comment: You send with the write() method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. You just need to push the infrastructure by calling flush() after writing:

```
printWriter.flush();
```